# undefined method `serializable_hash' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, serializable

i'm trying to_json in the following way

```
 @own_events.as_json(:include => {:created_date => {},:attendees => {}, :user => {}, :start_times => {}, :end_times =>{}} )
```

and created_date is a method like that

```
def created_date
  self.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
end
```

cause i need the created_at without the TZD .. but there is an error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `serializable_hash' for "14/04/2014 16:04:07":String):

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`:include` is used to include associations in the json, usually `has_many` or `belongs_to` associations.

To include methods like `created_date`, use `methods:`

Such as:

```
@own_events.as_json(include: [:attendees, :user, :start_times, :end_times], methods: :created_date )
```

Comment: SO should allow you to upvote again if it's been over a year since you last saw the answer and you found it useful again haha