# Rails 5.2 Rest API + Active Storage + React - Add attachment url to controller response

Tags: rails-api, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Would want to add the url for the attached file, while responding to get request for a nested resource (say Document) for parent resource (say Person).

```
# people_controller.rb  
def show
   render json: @person, include: [{document: {include: :files}}]
end


# returns
# {"id":1,"full_name":"James Bond","document":{"id":12,"files":[{"id":12,"name":"files","record_type":"Document","record_id":689,"blob_id":18,}]}


# MODELS
# person.rb  
class Person < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :document, class_name: "Document", foreign_key: :document_id
end

# document.rb
class Document < ApplicationRecord
   has_many_attached :files
end
```

Issue being, I want to show the file or provide a link to the file in a React frontend setup, which doesn't have helper methods like url_for. [As pointed out here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files).

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am looking into how to send files to a REST API using ActiveStorage on the backend. Can you share how you did that?

Comment: Unsure the comment section would take up all that explanation. Please refer https://medium.com/@anurag_722/send-files-to-rest-api-with-rails-5-2-active-storage-as-backend-65128a1170b wrote specifically to help you out. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What I have done is create this method in the model

```
def logo_url
  if self.logo.attached?
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.logo, only_path: true)
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

To add logo_url to your response json you can add `methods`.

```
render json: @person, methods: :logo_url
```

that is explained in the official guides =)

Comment: Eventually, I also did create a method in the model, and include that method in the json response. Wish rails had a straight forward attribute/method for the same.

Comment: A stupid question, but what is `logo` here? In my case it's undefined whatever I've tried. So this confirms that `logo_url` method is called, but it's not fully working. I'm using just one model so there is no `document` equivalent. Some more details would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

After digging in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb) of Active Storage, I found out model methods which exposed method called: **service_url**, which returns a short lived link to the attachment files.

Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137138/1320407) helped include the method inside the controller response json.

so, in order to achieve my required output I had to do

```
render json: @person, include: [{document: {include: {files: {include: {attachments: {include: {blob: {methods: :service_url}}}}} }}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :photos
end  

class MealsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: current_user.meals.map { |meal| meal_json(meal) }
  end

  def show
    render json: meal_json(current_user.meals.find!(params[:id]))
  end

  private

  def meal_json(meal)
    meal.as_json.merge(photos: meal.photos.map { |photo| url_for(photo) })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

All credit to [@JuanCarlosGamaRoa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51526199/5783745) for this, which worked for me.

I had a app where each 'product' has one 'main_image' attachment.

```
# app/models/product.rb
def main_image_url
  if self.main_image.attached?
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.main_image, only_path: true)
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/products/_product.json.jbuilder
json.extract! product, :id, :price, :created_at, :updated_at, :main_image_url
json.url product_url(product, format: :json)
```